# C# Restful Service Using WebInvoke POST method

Tags: c#, rest, post, webinvoke

My service is working well when i use:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/?id={id}")] 
string jdata(string id);
```

and my Method Implementation is

```
public string json(string id)
{
    return "Your typed String is : " id;
}
```

up to here it works well,
but I am bound to use `Method=POST` in WebInvoke,

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/?id={id}")]
string jdata(string id);
```

when I use this and call service, I have to face **Method Not Allowed.**
Please resolve my this little problem....

Comment: The two examples you supplied are the same. What are you doing differently when the you receive the error?

Comment: Dear That is pasted wrong,

Please consider Method="GET" on the 2nd line of the description of this question.
thanks.
please reply considering that My service is working well with Method - GET and when I change Method =POST then I face the error of <b>Method Not Allowed.</b>
Thanks

Comment: Dear please reply on this link if u could'not understand question on this page.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918199/c-sharp-restful-service-using-webinvoke-post
Thanks.