# C# Restful Service Using WebInvoke POST

Tags: web-services, rest, wcf-rest

I am developing a Restful service in C# and working well when I use

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle =     
WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/?id={id}")]
    string jdata(string id);
```

and my corrsponding function implementation is:

```
public string json(string id)
{
 return "You Typed : "+id;
}
```

Up to here all works well,
but when I change WenInvoke Method="POST" I have to face a "Method NOT Allowed.";

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = 
WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/?id={id}")]
    string jdata(string id);
```

Comment: Do you actualy send a POST request to the service? or are you trying to access it with 'only a URL in a webbrowser'? (WebBrowser URL = GET, webpage form = POST).

Get requires only a URL
Post requires a URL + Body

Comment: Why don't you just use MVC 4 Web API

Comment: @marvinSmit, Please just tell me how i can use Post method in WEBINVOKE.
Thanks

Comment: the WebInvoke attribute is defining your web service as "Post". It's the client that needs to make sure it's using the POST and not the GET (i.e. browing to the POST based RestFull service will yield a method not allowed). If you want to use a browser for testing you'll have to make a 'form' with the form fields being the parameters and the action of the form set to your web service operation endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

You get "Method not allowed" because you are reaching the Uri "json/?id={id}" via GET instead of POST.
Check this with your client (you didn't mention how you call this resource). Please give some further details how you are trying to use your web service in client. Is is .Net client?

To test your API I recommend using Fiddler - when you can explicitly specify whether to use GET or POST before sending an http request:
[image]

Another thing is, you might have unwittingly used "json" as Uri, but defined ResponseFormat as WebMessageFormat.Xml. Isn't it a little confusing for the client? Maybe you wanted to return JSON back? In that case, I would recommend using Json in both - request and response:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ValidateUser", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
             UriTemplate = "json")]
        string jdata(string id);
```

This is how your contract should look like and then in client

```
WebRequest httpWebRequest =
             WebRequest.Create(
               url);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
string json = "{\"id\":\"1234"\}"

 using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000000;

            WebResponse webrespon = (WebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(webrespon.GetResponseStream());
            string result = stream.ReadToEnd();

             Console.Out.WriteLine(result);
```

Above is just something i use to test my services. Hope it helps.